# Can't seem to use the SASS --watch command when installing

Tags: css, sass, chat, node-sass, livechat

Just node installed sass and keep getting an error when using:

`node-sass style.scss --watch`

This seems like a fairly recent bug since no one on the web has answered it.

Heres the error:

> An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
>   An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory
>   fs.js:965
>     binding.lstat(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path));
>             ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'style.scss'
>       at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:965:11)
>       at Object.module.exports.parseDir (/Users/glenpegado/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/sass-graph/sass-graph.js:153:10)
>       at Object.watcher.reset (/Users/glenpegado/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass/lib/watcher.js:17:21)
>       at watch (/Users/glenpegado/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:260:20)
>       at run (/Users/glenpegado/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:319:5)
>       at Object. (/Users/glenpegado/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass:405:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)

Comment: I can't help with node but I use Koala to compile my sass http://koala-app.com/ and that works awesomely for my needs

Comment: Run `node-sass —help` to see the manual. You can get the correct usage in the man pages.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that file doesn't exist where you think it does.

Comment: Orrrr… since "watch" watches a file or directory, you probably need to specify an output file that it will update with the changes it is watching for. Bad error, but not otherwise a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in the order of the parameters passed to `node-sass`. You passed the arguments reversed. The correct order is:

```
node-sass [options] <input> [output]
```

In case you want to watch a single file, you need to run:

```
node-sass --watch style.scss style.css
```

You can also use it to watch an entire folder. In that case you must specify the `--output` argument:

```
node-sass --watch source/folder --output destination/folder
```

You can read more about its usage and options [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/README.md).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the issue. You need to define the output path. Node-sass terminal command should follow this syntax:

```
$ node-sass [options] <input.scss> [output.css]
```

In your example, you only defined the source document.